# VUEJS submit event not TRIGGERED on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I want to submit a form and console log it's data but each time I click on the submit button, nothing happens NOT even an error in the console.
PS: I'm using vuelidate for form validation and tailwind. Below is the form's code:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
<div class="flex flex-1 flex-col" :class="{ 'input--error': $v.form.first_name.$error }">
  <label for="first-name" class="block mb-1 text-sm font-sofiaRegular font-medium text-gray-700">First name</label>
<input type="text" v-model="form.first_name" @blur="$v.form.first_name.$touch()" class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-sm font-sofiaRegular border-none rounded shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-40">

<div class="error" v-if="!$v.form.first_name.required && $v.form.first_name.$dirty">Field is required</div>
</div>

<div class="flex flex-1 flex-col" :class="{ 'input--error': $v.form.middle_name.$error }">
 <label for="middle-name" class="block mb-1 text-sm font-sofiaRegular font-medium text-gray-700">Middle name</label>
<input type="text" v-model="form.middle_name" @blur="$v.form.middle_name.$touch()"
  class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-sm font-sofiaRegular border-none rounded shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-40">

<div class="error" v-if="!$v.form.middle_name.required && $v.form.middle_name.$dirty">Field is required</div>
</div>

<div class="flex flex-1 flex-col" :class="{ 'input--error': $v.form.last_name.$error }">

<label for="last-name" class="block mb-1 text-sm font-sofiaRegular font-medium text-gray-700">Last name</label>
<input type="text" v-model="form.last_name" @blur="$v.form.last_name.$touch()" 
class="bg-gray-200 text-gray-500 text-sm font-sofiaRegular border-none rounded shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-green-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-40">

<div class="error" v-if="!$v.form.last_name.required && $v.form.last_name.$dirty">Field is required</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="text-sm font-medium tracking-wide px-4 py-2 bg-green-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-green-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 focus:ring-opacity-50">Send</button>


</form>
```

and, here's the **submit** function in my methods.

```
<script>

...
   data() {
        return {
            form: {
                first_name: '',
                middle_name: '',
                last_name: ''
            },
        }
    },
     methods: {
        submit() {
            // collect form data
            const application = {
                first_name: this.form.first_name,
                middle_name: this.form.middle_name,
                last_name: this.form.last_name
            }
        
            console.log("Apply form Data: ", application)
        }
    },
...
</script>
```

Comment: Solved... My submit button was outside the form tag, such a silly oversight!

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was that I had the submit button outside the form tag, such a silly oversight!

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit"></form>
<button class="...">Send</button>
```